# Skype Installation on Elementary OS

Tags: skype

I am a new Linux user, I am using Elementary OS and not much familiar with its features. I want help with skype installation. I have downloaded the skype from official website, however, I dont know how to install it on my laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have not tried this but it should work ...

- download the "DEB" package for linux (remember where it is downloaded)
- You can install it by using sudo apt install ./name.deb

this assumes you are in terminal app in the directory where the file exists
or you could specify the full path name of the file

Answer (score 0):

George Barbaz is right, his answer should work just fine.
How ever, here is a maybe more detailed explanation, because you stated you are new to the linux world:

*Open the files application and navigate to the folder, where the file you've downloaded is stored.*

*Right-click and click on 'Open in' ➝ 'Terminal'*

*Type in the following command*.

`sudo apt install -y ./nameofthefile.deb`

`apt` is the package manager used by ubuntu-based linux distributions like elementary, the `install` keyword explains itself, I guess, and the `-y` flag skips the confirmation dialog, you are normally prompted with and approves the actions taken directly. `.` is a substitution of the current directory that you are in. `apt` needs this to understand, that you want to install a local file and not one from a repository.

That's pretty much everything sumed up, I guess. Makes it maybe a bit more understandable for you.

Answer (score 0):

What other people have said is correct but I don't recommend you to install Skype on Linux.
Microsoft decided to stop updating their Skype app for Linux so it may stop working in the future and it may have security issues that aren't being patched. However, you can use [Skype on the web](https://web.skype.com) from any computer and browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an application called [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy.desktop) on the elementary OS AppCentre. When it's installed, you can either open the application and proceed as it instructs, or you can simply open Files, navigate to where the Skype installation file is located, click it and proceed with the installation.

You can also find Skype as a [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/) and [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) application.

Answer (score 0):

Skype is available for Linux from the [Skype website.](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/) as a .deb package.

Grab the latest version of Skype and then open up a terminal window. Using the `cd` command, move the terminal window into the `~/Downloads` directory:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then, to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Usually the process, in this case, will terminate with an error. To fix it:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

There is also, as mentioned above, a dedicated app for elementary that manages and installs .deb files.You can follow the direct link to the app [Eddy - direct link](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/)

Hope that helped you.

Comment: You can use also `gdebi` to install a downloaded deb file and don't care about dependencies because it will try to install them or abort the installation if doesn't find them. Also you could use `flatpak` or `snap` to install the latest Skype